# Saving and restoring ArrayList

Tags: java, android

My app takes two pictures and puts each URI into an ArrayList so that I can iterate it through it from a single ImageView. I know that the URIs are properly working and being added to the ArrayList. I assume that the activity dies on screen rotate for the camera (to take previously mentioned images) so I used onSaveInstanceState to keep the data I want to use. Before I did this, the app would crash right after taking the pictures. Now it doesn't, but I get a NullPointer when I try to setImage from the list. Am I doing something wrong?

Logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: my.package.myapplication, PID: 15047
                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(android.net.Uri)' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at my.package.myapplication.Person1Screen$5.onClick(Person1Screen.java:130)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5209)
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21174)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5477)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I get the NullPointer in the setImageURI at the bottom of the following:

```
happy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.happy_btn);
happy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            id = HAPPY;
            if(toggled){
                //picture mode
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
            else if(!toggled) {
                //display mode
                //happyIndex = 0;
                mainView.setImageURI(happyList.get(0)); // LINE 130
            }
        }
    });
```

I have the following in my onCreate:

```
happyList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        happyList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(HAPPY_LIST);
    }
```

My onSaveInstance:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList(HAPPY_LIST, happyList);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

My TakePictureIntent (to take two pictures either from camera or gallery) and onActivityResult (takes URIs and adds to list):

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    pictureCounter = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pictureCounter++;
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.w("error","IOException");
            }catch (NullPointerException nullEx) {
                Log.w("error","NullPointerException");
            }
            // Camera.
            final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
            for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
                final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
                final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                intent.setPackage(packageName);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                cameraIntents.add(intent);
            }
            // Filesystem.
            final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            // Chooser of filesystem options.
            final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");
            // Add the camera options.
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO) {
                final boolean isCamera;
                if (data == null) {
                    isCamera = true;
                } else {
                    final String action = data.getAction();
                    if (action == null) {
                        isCamera = false;
                    } else {
                        isCamera = action.equals(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    }
                }
                Uri selectedImageUri;
                if (isCamera) {
                    selectedImageUri = outputFileUri;
                } else {
                    selectedImageUri = data == null ? null : data.getData();
                }
               // mainView.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
              //  Log.d("Before adding", selectedImageUri.toString());
                happyList.add(selectedImageUri);
               // Log.d("Array:", happyList.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: no reason to override onResoreInstanceState and you are using a different name in onCreate.

Comment: @muratgu I'm getting the same problem with the updated code. I made changes in my post to what I have now.

Comment: well, maybe happyList is empty then? why should we assume it has at least one element?

Comment: @muratgu I debugged and printed the list right after I added to it and it isn't empty. I'll post my takePhotoIntent method and onActivityResult in hopes of shedding more light.

Comment: Can you please edit your question again to include the logcat? The answers below addressed the initial problem with the typo, but you now are probably getting a completely different NullPointerException error

Comment: @cricket_007 Added the logcat!

Comment: Yup. The ImageView is null at Person1Screen.java line 130... Please debug and see. Tip: `findViewById` can return null

Comment: @cricket_007 Why might findViewById(R.id.happy_btn) return null? Another button is found just fine using findViewById. The id is correct. When I run the app, the button itself also works to take the picture.

Comment: I'm just reading the logcat, and I only said the method can return null, not necessarily that it is.

Comment: `mainView` is what's null, anyways, so I'm not sure why you mentioned that other line

Comment: @cricket_007 Yep. I was getting the same error before I fixed the serializable thing too. I think it might be the way I'm asking the app to take two pictures directly after the other. When I call dispatchTakePhotoIntent, I simply looped it twice to 'take two pictures'. Are my assumptions on how onActivityResult works wrong? Maybe it finalizes the arrayList before I even took a picture?

Comment: You've thrown all the snippets of code into the question now, but youre missing the most important one related to the error. `mainView` is either never initialized, or it is null from a `findViewById` usage

Comment: @cricket_007 Wow. Thanks for pointing that out... I was still under the impression that the NullPointer was complaining about an empty arrayList which is why I mentioned that other button. I fixed mainView (another typo in code I didn't present) and I'm finally able to display the picture. Not sure if it's the right thing to do but I'll accept your answer below since it did correct my initial inquiry.

Comment: Yup ;) Takes practice to get good at reading the stacktrace and knowing what causes code to fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, it's recommended you store a key constant in your class. Main reason, to keep them consistent and avoid typos.

```
public static final String HAPPY_LIST = "happyList";
```

Now, use that whenever you save and restore

Second, I think these should be flipped because you want to put in the things you save, then do whatever the super call does

Also Uri objects are Parcelable, so use the appropriate method for that

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList(HAPPY_LIST, happyList);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Finally, you can either use the restored bundle in onRestoreInstanceState or in onCreate, but I don't think you need to do both.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, good to know. Unfortunately, I'm getting the same problem with the updated code. I made changes in my post to what I have now; I still get a NullPointer when calling the list.

Comment: Fixed. Uri objects aren't serializable, they are Parcelable

Answer (score 1):

In onSavedInstanceState() method you set the key as "happylist" change "array" in the if condition to "happylist"

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    happyList = (ArrayList<Uri>)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("happylist");
}
```

Comment: Updated my code, thanks for seeing my typo. Unfortunately, I'm getting the same problem with the updated code. I made changes in my post to what I have now; I still get a NullPointer when calling the list.